# System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request. calling a webservice dynamically

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, webservice-client

Iam calling a web service through my web service dynamically. I stored serviceName, MethodToCall, and array of parameters in my database table and execute these two methods to call a dynamic service url with .asmx extention and its method without adding its reference in my app. It works fine.

Following code is here.

```
public string ShowThirdParty(String strURL, String[] Params, String MethodToCall, String ServiceName)
        {

   String Result = String.Empty;

//Specify service Url without ?wsdl suffix.
            //Reference urls for code help
            ///http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/webservice_.aspx?msg=3197985#xx3197985xx
            //http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/CallWebServicesDynamic.aspx
            //String WSUrl = "http://localhost/ThirdParty/WebService.asmx";
            String WSUrl = strURL;

            //Specify service name
            String WSName = ServiceName;

            //Specify method name to be called
            String WSMethodName = MethodToCall;

            //Parameters passed to the method
            String[] WSMethodArguments = Params;
            //WSMethodArguments[0] = "20500";

            //Create and Call Service Wrapper
            Object WSResults = CallWebService(WSUrl, WSName, WSMethodName, WSMethodArguments);

            if (WSResults != null)
            {
                //Decode Results
                if (WSResults is DataSet)
                {
                    Result += ("Result: \r\n" + ((DataSet)WSResults).GetXml());
                }
                else if (WSResults is Boolean)
                {   
                   bool BooleanResult = (Boolean)WSResults;
                    if(BooleanResult)
                          Result += "Result: \r\n" + "Success";
                    else
                          Result += "Result: \r\n" + "Failure";
                }
                else if (WSResults.GetType().IsArray)
                {
                    Object[] oa = (Object[])WSResults;
                    //Retrieve a property value withour reflection...
                    PropertyDescriptor descriptor1 = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(oa[0]).Find("locationID", true);
                    foreach (Object oae in oa)
                    {
                        Result += ("Result: " + descriptor1.GetValue(oae).ToString() + "\r\n");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Result += ("Result: \r\n" + WSResults.ToString());
                }
            }
            return Result;
        }

        public Object CallWebService(string webServiceAsmxUrl,
       string serviceName, string methodName, string[] args)
        {

            try
            {
                System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
                Uri objURI = new Uri(webServiceAsmxUrl);
                //bool isProxy = client.Proxy.IsBypassed(objURI);
                //objURI = client.Proxy.GetProxy(objURI);
                //-Connect To the web service
               // System.IO.Stream stream = client.OpenRead(webServiceAsmxUrl + "?wsdl");

                string ccc = webServiceAsmxUrl + "?wsdl";// Connect To the web service System.IO.
                //string wsdlContents = client.DownloadString(ccc);
                string wsdlContents = client.DownloadString(ccc);
                XmlDocument wsdlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                wsdlDoc.InnerXml = wsdlContents;
                System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescription description = System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescription.Read(new XmlNodeReader(wsdlDoc));

                //Read the WSDL file describing a service.
                // System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescription description = System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescription.Read(stream);

                //Load the DOM

                //--Initialize a service description importer.
                ServiceDescriptionImporter importer = new ServiceDescriptionImporter();
                importer.ProtocolName = "Soap12"; //Use SOAP 1.2.
                importer.AddServiceDescription(description, null, null);

                //--Generate a proxy client. 

                importer.Style = ServiceDescriptionImportStyle.Client;
                //--Generate properties to represent primitive values.

                importer.CodeGenerationOptions = System.Xml.Serialization.CodeGenerationOptions.GenerateProperties;

                //Initialize a Code-DOM tree into which we will import the service.
                CodeNamespace codenamespace = new CodeNamespace();
                CodeCompileUnit codeunit = new CodeCompileUnit();
                codeunit.Namespaces.Add(codenamespace);

                //Import the service into the Code-DOM tree. 
                //This creates proxy code that uses the service.

                ServiceDescriptionImportWarnings warning = importer.Import(codenamespace, codeunit);

                if (warning == 0)
                {

                    //--Generate the proxy code
                    CodeDomProvider provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");

                    //--Compile the assembly proxy with the 
                    //  appropriate references
                    string[] assemblyReferences = new string[]  {
                       "System.dll", 
                       "System.Web.Services.dll", 
                       "System.Web.dll", 
                       "System.Xml.dll", 
                       "System.Data.dll"};

                    //--Add parameters
                    CompilerParameters parms = new CompilerParameters(assemblyReferences);
                    parms.GenerateInMemory = true; //(Thanks for this line nikolas)
                    CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromDom(parms, codeunit);

                    //--Check For Errors
                    if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
                    {

                        foreach (CompilerError oops in results.Errors)
                        {
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("========Compiler error============");
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(oops.ErrorText);
                        }
                        throw new Exception("Compile Error Occured calling WebService.");
                    }

                    //--Finally, Invoke the web service method
                    Object wsvcClass = results.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance(serviceName);
                    MethodInfo mi = wsvcClass.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);
                    return mi.Invoke(wsvcClass, args);
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Now the problem arraize when i have two different client servers. and calling a service from one server to the service deployed on other server. Follwing two kind of error log occurs. Cant find the exact reson for cope up this problem.

```
System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request.
 at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
 at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
 at MarkUsageHistoryInSTJH.InsertUpdateIssueItemAditionalDetail(String csvBarcode, String csvName, String csvPMGSRN, String csvGLN, String csvMobile, String csvPhone, String csvAddressLine1, String csvAddressLine2, String csvAddressLine3, String csvIsHospital)
```

and

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): 
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 172.17.13.7:80     
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)     

  at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception)
```

Comment: We had a similar issue when we were accessing one webservice.asmx from another.
I can tell you that this is because calling webservice has to wait for the other websrvice to send the response and it timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

Please Carry Out Following Steps :

1) First of all try to access  your service by adding reference of it.

It it works fine then we can say that there is no problem related to accessibility and permission.

2) If its not work then there is a problem with connection.
-->So Check Configuration in your service and try to set timeout for  your web service.
(http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ed89ae3c-e5f8-401b-bcc7-
333579a9f0fe/webservice-client-timeout)

3)Now try after setting the timeout.
it operation completes successfully after above change that means now you can check with your web client method(dymamic calling).

4) If still problem persists then this might be network latency issue. Check the n/w latency between your client and server.
it will helps you.